# How to post data on twitter without Intent sharing?

Tags: android, post, twitter

I want to post text,image and video in twitter from my app without opening twitter app.
I tried to find solution for this but can't get.
I don't want to use Intent to share data.
I want to post directly from my app.

Please give me proper solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

take a  look at these links--

http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/08/08/improved-twitter-oauth-android/

http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/13/guide-to-integrating-twitter-android-application/

http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2012/05/share-text-to-facebook-twitter-android.html

Answer (score 0):

To use twitter services you need to implement their api, you can download the oficial one here: https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/overview

There are some tutorials on how to use it (log in, post, show..)  on the same link.

---

Or you can try an unofficial one here:
http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html

It's provided by twitter itself, so it's safe.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I already use https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/overview .
I use https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/compose-tweets for post data. this will open twitter app. But i don't want like this.
I want to post directly in twitter from my app without opening twitter app.